# Regular expression to put quotes around each word

Tags: php, regex

Let's suppose I have a string like this

```
$str = "this is my string";
```

I need a regular expression in order to have

```
$str = "'this','is','my','string'";
```

I know that with this one

```
preg_match_all("#\w+#",$str,$mth);
```

I can get an array with single words but I'm not able to reach my goal. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = "'" . implode("','", explode(' ', $str)) . "'"
```

No regular expressions needed.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I choose your answer and I give a +1 to all the other users. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: Thank you. Don't forget to hit up the checkmark to formally mark it as answered.

Comment: My bad. I guess I jumped the gun there. I just get annoyed at people saying "Thanks for the help", and then vanishing into the aether forever. Glad to see you're not one of them :D

Comment: No problem. If you take a look at my profile you will see that I always accept an answer when I receive one. ;) Have a nice day

Comment: still `implode` but use `$words = preg_split('/\W+/', $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` then you can check to see if there are any words at all and you don't get empty strings `''` in the list when there are double spaces

Answer (score 2):

You could use `explode` instead:

```
$parts = explode(" ", $str);
```

Thus "$parts" will be the array of ["this", "is", "my", "string]. Then you could run through the array and add quotes around each word and finally doing:

```
$final = implode(",", $parts);
```

Comment: Plain explode will fail on other kind of whitespaces or multi spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use a regular expression?  You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to change all the spaces to the sequence `','` then append single quotes at the beginning and end:

```
$str = "'" . str_replace(" ", "','", $str) . "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the array of words, it's just a simple concat:

```
$quoted = '';
foreach($words as $word) {
    $quoted .= " '".$word."' ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join` / `implode` to generate the final string.

```
$str = "'". join("','", $mth). "'";
```

Or you could just use a direct `preg_replace`:

```
$str = "'". preg_replace("#\w+#", "','", $str). "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def str = "Fred,Sam,Mike,Sarah"<br/>
str.replaceAll(~"(\\\b)", "'")
```

This works well in Groovy. (version - 1.8.4)